# Extracting only updated content from .log file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, awk

I am trying to create a PowerShell script which will act as a watcher to a log file and point out the changes in log file.

Somehow I am not able to achieve the pointing out of changes, I tried the following code, here I tried to fetch changes in last 15 minutes but it did not worked:

```
$File = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log"
$Action = 'awk ' $0 >= from' from=$(date -u -d -15min "+####<%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S o'clock GMT>") error.log'
$global:FileChanged = $false

function Wait-FileChange {
param(
    [string]$File,
    [string]$Action
)
$FilePath = Split-Path $File -Parent
$FileName = Split-Path $File -Leaf
$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($Action)

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $FilePath, $FileName -Property @{ 
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
}
$onChange = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Changed -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true}

while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

& $ScriptBlock 
Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $onChange.Id
}

Wait-FileChange -File $File -Action $Action
```

Later I changed the `$Action` part with the following code which will fetch last 5 lines and I got it working fine

```
$Action = 'Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log" | Select-Object -last 5 '
```

But my target is to watch the change and print the changes which are made.
Can anyone help me out regarding this, any help is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

> But my target is to watch the change and print the changes which are
>   made.

Are you aware that the `Get-Content` cmdlet has a `-Wait` switch:

```
Get-Content $File -Wait
```

Comment: I know very less about it, ~Wait is a kind of switch parameter, but I have read somewhere that on windows it is not much used . But how it could help me?